# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/RecipientId

Tags: itext

I have searched on the stack overflow and on other web sites for below code to concatinate two pdf files but getting below error.

```
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

    public class Concatenate {

        public static final String RESULT= "concatenated.pdf";
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
            String[] files = ["1.pdf","2.pdf"];
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
            document.open();
            PdfReader reader;
            int n;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
                n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                {
                    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                }
                copy.freeReader(reader);
                reader.close();
            }
            document.close();
        }
    }
```

And this is the error I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/bouncycastle/cms/RecipientId at 
      java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at 
      java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531) at 
      java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651) at 
      java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467) at
      org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass.getSAMMethod(CachedSAMC‌​lass.java:135) at 
      org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isSAM(ClassInfo.java:280) at
```

Comment: Below is error:
    
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/RecipientId at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531) at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651) at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467) at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass.getSAMMethod(CachedSAMClass.java:135) at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isSAM(ClassInfo.java:280) at

Comment: Put this in your question, you can edit it.

Comment: @MukeshSingh Three possible causes: (1) You are using the wrong BouncyCastle version, (2) you don't have BouncyCastle in your CLASSPATH, (3) you have more than one BouncyCastle version in your CLASSPATH. Check the POM file of the iText version you are using to find out which version of BC you have to use. Use that version **and only that version!**

Answer (score 1):

It's working now with below JAR:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lowagie
I followed your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please add bouncycastle library in your system classpath variable.

> set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib_path_of_bouncycastle

Comment: That's only one possibility. Maybe @MukeshSingh has *a version* of BouncyCastle in his CLASSPATH, but not *the required version*. `RecipientId` was missing in older versions of BouncyCastle. Another possibility is that Mukesh has more than one version of BouncyCastle in his CLASSPATH... In short: your answer is too simplistic. It may solve the problem, but I doubt it.